# Why can you electrolyze liquids but not solids?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

Table salt can be electrolysed in molten form, water in liquid form etc etc but why can it not be electrolysed in solid form? What is the effect of allotrope

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_electrolyte